# Deploying multiple container in kubernetes through a deployed app

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am using `minikube` for deployment in my local machine.
I am deploying an app with help of helm charts. My deployment script looks like

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "app.fullname" . }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
    spec:
      volumes:
          - name: dockersock
            hostPath:
                path: "/var/run/docker.sock"
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          volumeMounts:
              - name: dockersock
                mountPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
          args:
            - python3 runMyApp.py;
          resources:
            limits:
              nvidia.com/gpu: {{ .Values.numGpus }}
```

My script `runMyApp.py` when executed launch 4 other containers and I want that Kubernetes deploy them as well at minikube and this is expected behavior from my understanding. 
But When I  other 4 containers they were deployed on host machine, just like I executed some `docker run` command on my host machine. 
To verify that I was not mistaken,
so I tried to access them through other application using which is in minikube cluster but I couldn't. Then I tried accessing the application from the local environment and I was able to do that.

Is there any flaw in my understanding. If the behaviour is expected then what can I do to deploy other application in `k8s` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create new pods from within your python script, you should use the Kubernetes Python client library: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python .

When you running docker run inside your script, kubernetes isn't aware of those containers, and they are just orphand containers running on your node host machine.